# jQuery text rotator help needed

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have come across a requirement where I need to show list of UL LI tags in a specific way.

I need to show x no of items in a div. After specific duration next set of x element should show and previous should hide.

Here's fiddle which will demonstrate what I am targeting to. I have 13 list items in a row. It should load 5 items for the first time, next 5 items for the second time and only 3 items for the third time. It should reset than again with showing first 5 items.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rzWUR/5/)

I hope I am more clear with my requirement.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What is it that's not working?  It's not entirely clear from your question because the jsfiddle appears to be operational.

Comment: It's loading list items in segments but at the end it shows item 11,12,13,1,2. Which should show only 11,12 and 13 item.

Answer (score 1):

I moved it down to 7 (it was taking too long to loop through them all when I was making changes)

It looks like the problem is the check to see how many there are visible is the problem, my guess is it should look like this instead:

```
if(end_of_list){
    //remove all from visible, then:
    $(this).detach().appendTo('ul#ticker').removeAttr('style');
} else {
    $('#ticker li:lt(' + 5 + ')').animate({ marginTop: '-120px' }, 800);
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle I was playing with. The end of list calculation is not there though:

http://jsfiddle.net/rzWUR/9/

Comment: I tried adding your code in jsfiddle but that didn't worked out. I might have done something wrong. Can you pass on the working url please.

Comment: Thanks for the jsfiddle. It should restart once it reaches to end.